# How to play ExoPlayer from local file .mp4?

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I'm just started learning android and
I want to try to play videos from local storage with Exoplayer.

I have list videos from local storage by using Recyleview.

This is my code, I'm using SDK 32 and Exoplayer 2.14

 **MainActivity**

```
public void onFileClicked(File file) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlayerActivity.class)
                .putExtra("video", file.getAbsoluteFile()));
}
```

**PlayerActivity**

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
    String url = intent.getStringExtra("video");
    ExoPlayer player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
    PlayerView playerView = findViewById(R.id.player);
    playerView.setPlayer(player);

    MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(url);
    player.addMediaItem(mediaItem);

    player.prepare();
    player.play();
```

I'm trying using intent it's not working. 

What should I do?

Comment: For a test use exo player in mainactivity directly.

Comment: `it's not working` Sorry, but we have no idea what you mean by that. Errors? Exceptions?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.videoplayer1.PlayerActivity.onCreate(PlayerActivity.java:31)

Comment: Well show the code that causes that exception. And tell which statement exactly.

Comment: String url = intent.getStringExtra("video"); After debug, I see my error. I can't get string url from intent, it's null

Comment: If you use getStringExtra() you should have put a String with intent.putExtra(). Now what did you put?